# Grunt/Bundler wont use specified sass version

Tags: ruby, responsive-design, sass, bundler, compass-sass

We have a project with Grunt and Bundler setup.  All of these installed without issue.  Gemfile.lock generated, proper gems pulled down, and grunt files created with npm.  We start our watch on the project and it bombs on sass compile because it's using the wrong version of sass and not the one specified in the gemfile.

This is on windows by the way...

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'sass', '~> 3.2'
gem 'compass', '~> 0.12'
gem 'susy', '~> 1.0'
```

Gemfile.lock

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    chunky_png (1.3.1)
    compass (0.12.6)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.2.19)
    fssm (0.2.10)
    sass (3.2.19)
    susy (1.0.9)
      compass (>= 0.12.2)
      sass (>= 3.2.0)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  compass (~> 0.12)
  sass (~> 3.2)
  susy (~> 1.0)
```

Comment: Do you need to have several versions of sass installed? The way I've found of dealing with this issue is to remove all of the sass versions except the one I want to use.

Comment: nwalton, the whole point of bundler is to be able to have multiple versions of gems installed and be able to specify the ones to use for a particular project.  That way you or your team isnt always installing/removing gems when switching between project.  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to limit your gems to only those in your bundle (listed in your Gemfile), you should prefix your commands with `bundle exec` when running them in the terminal.

eg. if you were running `sass --watch` then you would run `bundle exec sass --watch` to make sure you use the version in your bundle.

Documentation on `bundle exec`: http://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html

Comment: We are using a grunt watch on the directory since we have some other process to be executed with the sass.  Any idea how to get it to work in that regard?

Comment: hmm, and because grunt isnt a gem in your bundle, you can't just do `bundle exec grunt`... can you tell grunt (I'm not super familiar with grunt but I believe it has a Gruntfile of some sort with commands in it?) to use `bundle exec sass` somehow?

Comment: No luck on Grunt yet but doing a "bundle exec compass watch"  worked for the sass part.

Comment: The trick was using "bundle exec grunt watch" prepending the bundle command forced the use of the specified versions.  Thanks, and hope this helps other out in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Based on an informal experiment (adding a GEMFILE to my project at the same level of my Gruntfile), if you're using a Compass task and set the task option "bundleExec" to true, the task should rely on bundler to handle versions and dependencies. With this setup, a lockfile was created when just running "grunt server" (not "bundle exec grunt server"). Anyone please correct me if this is wrong or misleading advice. Either method seems to work in my environment.

Answer (score 0):

On unix, you can check with the command:

`which sass`

Which should return something like:

`/Users/[username]/.rbenv/shims/sass`

If it is something like `/usr/bin/sass` then you need to prepend your command with `bundle exec` as @sevenseacat mentions.